# How can i add multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

How can I add multiple conditions in JavaScript? I don't want to check with the `&&`, I want to know if there is a way like `elseif` or I don't know, to check all conditions if the first one is `false` then go to another and if that too is `false` go to `else`. In my example if I write 'blank' in the text field it will show me nothing. The code won't work but if I delete the code from the `elseif`(*) part is going to work just fine. Why my `elseif` doesn't work? I tried to write something different than "blank" to check my `elseif` condition too, but I don't know why it doesn't work. This is my code:

```js
function Test() {
  var test = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var para = document.getElementById('hidden');

  if (test == "blank") {
    document.write(test.length);
  }
  ( * ) - > elseif(test = "Cristian") {

    para.innerHTML = "this is first para";
  } < -( * )
  else {
    para.innerHTML = "this is second para";
    para.style.font = "italic bold 20px arial,serif";


  }
}
```

```html
<p id="hidden">Surprise!</p>

<input type="text" id="name" />

<input type="button" onclick="Test()" value="press me" />
```

Comment: `elseif` should be `else if` .... `test="Cristian"` should be `test=="Cristian"` - browsers have **developer tools** for developers, one of which is a console that would've told you that there was a problem with `elseif`

Comment: BTW, a good habit to get into is to *always* use `===` and `!==` for comparison unless you specifically require the type coercion semantics of `==`.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks man

Answer (score 2):

You were close...

Instead of writing `elseif` you should add a space and write `else if`

**AND**

To compare element you should use `==` or `===`.

`=` is used for initialization

Comment: the == vs = ... seems to have known it in the `if` and forgotten it in the `else if` !!

Comment: I'm new to programming, now im learning so that's why i made this newbie mistakes :D but thanks for advices.

Comment: @CristianOvidiu You should follow some tutorial instead of trying stuff. It will be better for you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `switch`-statement:

```
switch(test){
  case: "test":
    document.write(test.length);
    break;
  case: "Christian":
    para.innerHTML = "this is first para";
    break;
  default:
    para.innerHTML = "this is second para";
    para.style.font = "italic bold 20px arial,serif";
}
```